# dll fails to load in running jcc

Tags: python, dll, jcc

When running:

```
python -m jcc.main
```

I get the error

`C:\Python26\python.exe: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`

I checked and the directory that jcc.dll is in the PATH.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `python -m jcc.__main__ --find-jvm-dll`

Comment: Oh my; you're the guy who has all the precompiled python libraries as windows binaries! Not sure if you know this, but one more small question, if I get a NoClassDefFoundError, does that mean I should be appending it as a --package? I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject, but --package org.json doesnt quite work.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a lib required by jcc.dll - most likely msvcr71.DLL
please read the updated hints at http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/pylucene-extra/wiki/PyLucene

Hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.